# MVC CheckBox binding back to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, model-binding

so I've looked everywhere for an answer to this peculiar problem, but I couldn't find the exact solution. Lots of similar problems, but not one that solves my exact problem, so apologies if this has already been answered.

I have the following (simplified) **models**:

```
public abstract class SimpleModel {
    public List<SimpleFieldModel> Fields{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class SimpleFieldModel {
    public List<ListItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ListItemModel {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

With the following **SimpleModel View**:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Fields.Count; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(Model.Fields[i])
}
```

And the following **SimpleFieldModel View**:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Selected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].Text)
}
```

And this produces the expected **markup**:

```
<input name="Fields[5].Items[0].Selected" id="Fields_5__Items_0__Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" data_val="89">
<input name="Fields[5].Items[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Fields[5].Items[0].Text" id="Fields_5__Items_0__Text" type="hidden" value="Option 1">
```

And when this is posted to the **controller**, I receive the following:

- **form-data**: Fields[5].Items[0].Selected = "true,false"
- **model**: Fields[5].Items[0].Selected = false

I have had to write a method to populate my collection with the data from the form, but I feel that Razor should be taking care of this for me, but it doesn't seem to be working.

### Edit

It would appear the root cause may be down to the fact I'm expecting to receive an abstract model into my controller, as so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SimpleModel model)
{
}
```

To overcome this, I have the following **model binder**:

```
public class SimpleModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ConcreteModelType");
        var type = Type.GetType(
            (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
            true
        );
        if (!typeof(SimpleModel).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad Type");
        }
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = 
        ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);

        return model;
    }
}
```

The strange thing though, is that at the point of exiting the above binder, the model has the correct number of Fields, and these each have their correct and expected Items. But, when I enter into the controller method, my model appears to have been altered, as it's now missing the Items from the Fields.

I apologise for not including all code initially, but I cannot provide access to the full code-base.

### Further Update

I think it might also be relevant to mention that I also have a *SimpleFieldModelBinder*. This is as so:

```
public class SimpleFieldModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(string.Format("{0}.{1}", bindingContext.ModelName, "ConcreteFieldModelType"));
        var type = Type.GetType(
            (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
            true
        );
        if (!typeof(SimpleFieldModel).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad Type");
        }
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);

        return model;
    }
}
```

So, when I exit the SimpleModelBinder, I have all my fields, and they have their correct Items in place (although unbound to recent form changes). Yet, my controller seems to be receiving a list of SimpleFieldModel objects which are missing their relevant Items list.

Things are definitely going wrong with the SimpleFieldModelBinder. If I take it out, my *SimpleModel* contains a list of the abstract *SimpleFieldModel* objects. But, if I leave it in, the controller receives a *SimpleModel* with the correct concrete types inside its Fields list, but these are all cleared of their *Items*.

### Another Update

I added some code in the SimpleFieldModelBinder, so that it populates the Items collection from the form data. On exiting the CreateModel, the collection was intact (and had the appropriate Selected values in place). Yet when I get to my controller (which I have to assume is the next step from binding?) These Items collections have been removed. One thing that's slightly suspicious though, is that the first Field **has** its Items in place, but all other fields do not. I suspect the binding is only working for the first item in the Fields collection, even though during debugging, I hit the SimpleFieldModelBinder for all the fields.

What might I be missing?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: You POST method just needs a parameter `SimpleModel model` (i.e. to match the model you pass to the view) and the `Items` property will be correctly bound with each `Selected` and `Text` property (you don't create form controls for `Value` so that property will be `null` and its not clear why you doing `new { data_val = Model.Items[i].Value }`)

Comment: But you code will not generate that html - it will not have the `Fields[5]` prefix - it will be just `name="Items[0].Selected"` unless there is something else you have not shown us

Comment: Quite right. My model is more complex. I'll try and add more to this to help explain the situation. Thanks.

Comment: @Oxonhammer. If your POST method has a parameter `SimpleModel model`, then `model` will be correctly bound with the values in your form. (and is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model.Fields)` to generate the correct html for all items in your collection - no loops)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it sounds like the code I have would be appropriate then, but for some reason, the Selected value isn't being populated from the form collection. I'll have a look and see if there is something else going on, Thanks

Comment: So long as your your indexers start at zero and are consecutive (for both `Fields` and `Items`) then it will bind fine (but if your do not have `Fields[0]...`, `Fields[1]...` etc then binding will fail unless you have a property for the collection indexer

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I think my problem is coming from the fact that my **SimpleModel** is actually an abstract class. I have a custom ModelBinder to create a new instance of the actual type that I need, and I think it's this that is creating a new set of Fields, with a fresh set of Items in each. This would appear to be then not binding correctly from the form. I also have a custom model binder for each Field, so I guess this should be dealing with any custom needs. Would this be correct?

Comment: Would have been worth mentioning that important information in your question - and your code does not even show it as being abstract :). And you have not shown the code for your ModelBinder(s) so a but hard to help.

Comment: I will edit the question @StephenMuecke, as I wasn't even aware that was relevant information. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to create a simple project for this lot, as I can see that the list of Items is getting dropped during binding, so I'm going to simulate what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Please copy this to your Visual Studio.  This should help you.

Controller/Models

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class SimpleModel
    {
        public List<ListItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListItemModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index29(SimpleModel sm)
    {
        //put breakpoint here to interrogate passed in model
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index29()
    {
        ListItemModel lim = new ListItemModel { Selected = false, Text = "aText", Value = "aValue" };
        ListItemModel limTwo = new ListItemModel { Selected = true, Text = "bText", Value = "bValue" };
        SimpleModel sm = new SimpleModel();
        sm.Items = new List<ListItemModel>();
        sm.Items.Add(lim);
        sm.Items.Add(limTwo);

        return View(sm);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.HomeController.SimpleModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index29</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.Label(Model.Items[i].Text)

                //modify the next line
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(
                    m => Model.Items[i].Selected)

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].Text)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].Value)
            }

            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```